# Import EDI file into Access line by line

Tags: vba, ms-access, import, edi

I need to import into Access table this EDI text file ( ' as line terminator):

```
UNA:+.?' 
UNB+UNOC:3+BRANDEUROPE+ANYCODE+180206:1121+5439'
UNH+5439-1+DESADV:D:99B:UN'
BGM+351+0089430043+9'
DTM+11:20180205:102'
DTM+137:20180205:102'
MEA+WT+AAD+KGM:2126.100'
MEA+CT+SQ+NMP:00000'
NAD+DP+0017309707++NameStreet 22+Rome++00100+IT'
CTA+DL'
NAD+SU+DE++BRAND Systems+Rome+Rome++00100+IT'
CTA+DL'
TOD+6++CIP'
CPS+1'
PAC+2++BX'
MEA+WT+G+KGM:88'
PCI+24'
GIN+ML+AL7B009435+AL7B009438'
LIN+1++46550705:VP'
PIA+1+4114793:BP'
IMD+A++:::C833dn-EURO'
QTY+12:2'
RFF+OP:44CKV07S:000001'
CPS+2'
PAC+1++BX'
MEA+WT+G+KGM:0.01'
PCI+24'
LIN+1++01182907:VP'
PIA+1+4113617:BP'
IMD+A++:::RAM-256MB-C3/C5/C6/C7/MC3/MC5/C8'
QTY+12:1'
RFF+OP:44CKV07S:000003'
CPS+3'
PAC+4++BX'
MEA+WT+G+KGM:43.2'
PCI+24'
LIN+1++46361802:VP'
PIA+1+4114805:BP'
IMD+A++:::Tray-C5x2/MC5x3'
QTY+12:4'
RFF+OP:44CKV07S:000006'
```

This is the result I need:

```
0089430043 05/02/2018 46550705 AL7B009435
0089430043 05/02/2018 46550705 AL7B009438
```

etc...

and this is what I tried:

```
Public Function import1()

Dim strFilename As String: strFilename = "C:\despatch.txt"
Dim strTextLine, CodProd, DataDoc As String
Dim SNarray() As String
Dim NumDoc As Long
Dim nPAC, NumRig, intCount As Integer
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile

    Open strFilename For Input As #iFile

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, strTextLine
        strTextLine = Replace(strTextLine, "'", "")

        'BGM
        If Left(strTextLine, 3) = "BGM" Then
            NumDoc = Mid(strTextLine, 9, 10)
        End If

        'DTM
        If Left(strTextLine, 6) = "DTM+11" Then
            DataDoc = Mid(strTextLine, 14, 2) & "/" & Mid(strTextLine, 12, 2) & "/" & Mid(strTextLine, 8, 4)
        End If

        'CPS = numero record
        If Left(strTextLine, 3) = "CPS" Then
            NumRig = Val(Mid(strTextLine, 5, 3))
        End If

        'PAC = numero di matricole da estrarre
        If Left(strTextLine, 3) = "PAC" Then
            nPAC = Val(Mid(strTextLine, 5, 3))
        End If

        'GIN
        If Left(strTextLine, 3) = "GIN" Then

        'strTextLine.MoveNext

        End If

        'LIN
        If Left(strTextLine, 3) = "LIN" Then
            CodProd = Mid(strTextLine, 8, 8)
        End If

        'strTextLine.MovePrevious

            SNarray = Split(Mid(strTextLine, 8), "+")

                For intCount = LBound(SNarray) To UBound(SNarray)
                    Debug.Print NumDoc & " " & DataDoc & " " & NumRig & " " & CodProd & " " & SNarray(intCount)
                Next
        'strTextLine.MovePrevious
        'strTextLine.MovePrevious
    Loop
    Close #iFile
End Function
```

Before to import GIN record with serial numbers, I need to achieve the LIN record with che product code, and then pass them to variables.
I've tried with .MoveNext and then with two .MovePrevious but it gives me error: object needed.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use `line input` to parse an EDIFACT file. You must implement a routine that detects the UNA segment and sets all the delimiters from it and must take into account the `?` escape character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved (I really don't know how I did), here my code:

```
Function GetLine() As String()

Dim FSO As Object, objFile, objFolderIN, objFolderOUT As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolderIN = FSO.GetFolder("C:\IN")
Set objFolderOUT = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Archivio")

Dim data, elem, comp
Dim i As Integer
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
Dim Elements(99, 3) As String
Dim mychar As String
Dim NumDoc As Long

i = 1
For Each objFile In objFolderIN.Files

    Open objFile For Input As #iFile

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, data
        'Debug.Print data
            mychar = Input(1, #1)    ' Get one character.
        If mychar = "'" Then Exit Do ' End of Segment
        If mychar = vbCr Or _
            mychar = vbLf Then
            'Continue
        ElseIf mychar = "?" Then
            mychar = Input(1, #1) ' Skip Line Breaks and Escape
            data = data & mychar
        ElseIf mychar = "'" Then
        Exit Do
        ElseIf mychar = "+" Then ' Element separator
            Elements(elem, comp) = data
            data = ""
            comp = 1
            elem = elem + 1
        ElseIf mychar = ":" Then ' Composite separator
            Elements(elem, comp) = data
            data = ""
            comp = comp + 1
        Else ' Regular data
            data = data & mychar
        End If
    Loop
    Elements(elem, comp) = data
    GetLine = Elements
Close #iFile

i = i + 1
Next objFile

'BGM
If Elements(0, 0) = "BGM" Then
   NumDoc = Elements(2, 1)
   Debug.Print NumDoc
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a function that parses an EDIFACT segment, it's not debugged but it shows the algorithm to read the EDI data.  It can be easily adapted to read ANSI X12.

```
Function GetLine() as String()
    Dim Elements as String(99,3)
    Do Until EOF(1)
        mychar = Input(1, #1)            ' Get one character
        If mychar = vbCr Or \
           mychar = vbLf Then            ' Skip Line Breaks  
           Continue
        Else If mychar = "?" Then        ' Process Escape
           If EOF(1) Then Exit Do        ' Reached end of file
           mychar = Input(1, #1)
           data = data & mychar          ' Treat next char as regular
        Else If mychar = "'" Then        ' End of Segment
           Exit Do     
        Else If mychar = "+" Then        ' Element separator
            Elements(Elem,Comp) = data
            data = ""
            Comp = 1
            Elem = Elem + 1
        Else If mychar = ":" Then        ' Composite separator
            Elements(Elem,Comp) = data
            data = ""
            Comp = Comp + 1
        Else                             ' Regular data
            data = data & mychar
        End If
    Loop
    Elements(Elem,Comp) = data
    GetLine = Elements
End Function
```

Example use

```
'BGM
If Elements(0,0) = "BGM" Then
   NumDoc = Elements(2,1)  
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Stavr00 but with your code I get this error:
Runtime error '62' Error Description "Input Past End Of File"

Comment: Added EOF Check

Comment: same error on this line:
mychar = Input(1, #1)    ' Get one character.
see your code below I've adapted...